# How to save themes of a presentation to use them in another?

Tags: themes, libreoffice

I downloaded presentations with nice themes I would like to use myself.

The only way I found was to delete all the content and write my own.

Isn't there a better solution than this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see chapter 2 "Using Slide Masters, Styles, and Templates" of the LibreOffice Impress Guide, esp. the stuff about 'slide masters':
https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/5/5b/IG3500-ImpressGuideLO.pdf

more documentation at:
http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/documentation/

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific where to find this feature? Basically exporting master pages and/or presentation backgrounds.

Comment: -1 Even after reading alot from your linked pdf, I did not find the required information ... this should not be the accepted answer ! Even the basic information "use templates!" is missing!

Answer (score 7):

1. Open the presentation which runs the nice theme
2. Select the slide which runs the nice theme
3. Press: `File --> Templates --> Save as Template`. Give some name to it and save it ( I used the predefined folder "My Templates")
4. On the presentation you want to use this template, right click on a slide slide `--> slide design --> Load` and select the template you saved
5. Or, if you want to exchange a existing design go to `View --> Master --> Slide Master` There you can again right-click and change the slight-design of the current Master.

Tested with LibreOffice Version: 4.2.8.2

Answer (score 0):

when you have the desired template open you should go to `File --> Templates --> Save As Template...` Click on save, enter template name and validate... When you wish to use this template any other time just do this; `File --> Templates --> Manage` Select the Presentation tab and choose the template you saved. Hope this helps you!